# What's the dustjs default dynamic partial path?

Tags: dust.js

I'm trying to render a template using the render method like below

```
adaro.render('name', mailData, function(error, output){
    if(error){
        console.log('load template error', error);
        reject(error);  
    } else {
        console.log('OUTPUT:', output);
        resolve(output);
    }       
});
```

And here's the template file:

```
{>"layouts/message"/}

{<title}
Welcome
{/title}
```

However, I keep getting error saying

```
[Error: Template Not Found: layouts/message]
```

That's because I don't know what's the root path of the dustjs render.

In expressJS, I can set the views path like below

```
app.set('views', "/path/to/views/folder");
```

But I'm planning to render it via the API itself and not via res.render.

So my question is how to I set the root path of the dust.render such that the partial will refer to the root path like below.

```
{>"layouts/message"/}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dust doesn't have the concept of a filesystem, because Dust is purposely filesystem-agnostic. Instead, you need to tell Dust how it should handle requests for a template that isn't yet in its cache.

The reason for this is that Dust is designed to run on both the server and in the browser, so it wouldn't be helpful to have native filesystem support baked-in, for example.

To tell Dust how it should load new templates, you need to provide an `onLoad` function. Dust will invoke this function as `dust.onLoad(templateName, callback)` whenever you try to include a new template that isn't in the Dust cache.

If you use something like `consolidate.js`, it includes a simple `onLoad` implementation for Dust. Here's consolidate's:

```
engine.onLoad = function(path, callback){
  if ('' == extname(path)) path += '.' + ext;
  if ('/' !== path[0]) path = views + '/' + path;
  read(path, options, callback);
};
```